# How i can get all child LinearLayout in kaspresso

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-espresso, kakao

I have LinearLayout with child the same type And try get all child

This example get one element:

```
val text1 = KTextView {
        withParent {
            withId(R.id.linear_layout)
        }
        withIndex(0) {
            withTag("matchTag")
        }
    }
```

But i want get all child elements in ArrayList
How i can get all child LinearLayout in kaspresso ?